# cycle through output and add to database

Tags: django

An API call returns some data that I want to upload into the database, it returns about 5000 records. I only want to run this manually when needed.

```
[
  {
    "id": "01",
    "symbol": "xyz",
    "name": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "id": "02",
    "symbol": "abc",
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": "04",
    "symbol": "fhf",
    "name": "fhf"
  },
  {
    "id": "05",
    "symbol": "gxfg",
    "name": "gxfg"
  },
]
```

Is there a way I can cycle through each one and upload it to a model? The model will have matching field names os `ID` `Symbol` and `Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might be missing something, but if all you want to do is take that data and create models with it then you can just do this:

```py
dataList = [
  {
    "id": "01",
    "symbol": "xyz",
    "name": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "id": "02",
    "symbol": "abc",
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": "04",
    "symbol": "fhf",
    "name": "fhf"
  },
  {
    "id": "05",
    "symbol": "gxfg",
    "name": "gxfg"
  },
]


for index in range(len(dataList)):
    if not YourModel.objects.filter(name=dataList[index]['name']).exists():
        YourModel.objects.create(
            id = int(dataList[index]['id']),
            symbol = dataList[index]['symbol'],
            name = dataList[index]['name'])
```

This uses the [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists) function in django, which can be very fast.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  Just 1 thing. Is there a way to say if name already exists then skip?

Comment: Sure, I'll get back to you with an edit.

Comment: I think the edited answer might help.  Use the exists() function in django:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists